rsync reuse tcp connection?
I have some files need to sync from local to remote. rsync is a good choice.
But the problem occurs when I want to pass different data to different remote directory.
For Example:
rsync ./file1 root@remote:/file1_dir
rsync ./file2 root@remote:/file2_dir

It's ok, but it build two tcp connections.
If the building connection is slow(maybe the bad network environment). This will be wasty.
Can I merge the two command into one? in order to build connection only once.
Or, can the second command reuse the connection of first?
Thanks for your attention.
